# Hide objectes in specific animations

Tags: animation

I have 3 animations

1. idle
2. walk
3. axe

an object should be visible only in the axe animation. I have tryed setting the visibility properties (viewport and renders) for the keyframes but when I run the animation I have to manually select the correct animation in the outline for the singole object. Also, when I export in fbx the object is always visible. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks
Giulio

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Mask](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mask.html) Modifier:

1. On your Axe object Edit Mode assign all vertices to a group and set the weight less than 1.0

[image]

1. Apply the Mask Modifier to the object whose visibility you want to vary
2. Create a New Scene with (Full Copy vs Linked) -- can used link and then Unlink the changeable (beyond scope of this answer)
3. In the "Is Visible" Scene, set the Mask Threshold > Vertex Weight:

[image]

4. In the "Is Invisible" scene, set the Mask Threshold < Vertex Weight:

[image]

5. Or if you want an item to appear/disappear in the same scene, animate the Threshold or Weight (see note in previous screenshot)

Comment: Thanks James! I'm trying to reproduce this behaviour, how can I unlink an object from one a scene ?